# Display 0 rows in list view webpart if there is no filter set?

Tags: 2007, web-part, document-library, connected-web-parts, list-view-web-part

I am trying to setup a custom page that uses the document library "A" in multiple webparts to show only certain columns based on a "trickle-down" connection system.

(please note ALL list view webparts referenced below display document library A)

So far I have setup 6 webparts. 1 is a text filter webpart that has a connection to the main list view webpart. The other 4 webparts are list views that only display certain columns of a row that is displayed by itself via a connection on a selected row from the main list view webpart.(I am using easy tabs for a more eloquent view)

So far that works. If I search it only affects the main list view webpart and gives me my results. Upon checking the circle next to one of the documents (before or after searching) the subsequent 4 listview webparts are properly filtered to only show that row.

My question is: How can I make it so that the 4 child webparts display 0 rows if there isnt a row selected in the main webpart? (Preferably with OOTB features but I'm not against code (-: )

Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Have you used any Web Part connections between these web parts, how the 4 web parts show only that row which was selected in Main View ?

Comment: If you read my post carefully you'll see that ALL 6 webparts have some form of connection. For 4 that only show the row from above: Connections - get sort/filter from - "Main list" and when it prompts you for a column select which ever your interested in (IT HAS TO BE SHOWN IN THE CURRENT VIEW and preferably a unique one) and hit next - select the same column and hit finish. Voila!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost forgot I posted this until I started searching google for another answer.
Anyways. The answer is to use SPD to convert the list view webparts into Data view webparts and use parameters and the Display text if no match is found setting.

Details and step by step guide can be found in this blog post: [Connecting web parts with a selector and a detail pane](http://sarahlhaase.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/connecting-web-parts-with-a-selector-and-a-detail-pane-moss-2007-version/)